# When in English people say that things have needs, is it literal?

Tags: synonyms, figurative-language

In Spanish, things cannot have needs. Only living creatures have needs. In English, instead, it’s very common for things to have needs, as in “This floor needs to be washed” to mean “This floor should be washed”.

Question: when you hear phrases like this, do you take it as a metaphor/allegory/stretch of language/figure of speech, something substituting the literal “should/ought to”, or as something literal (i.e., you take “to need” to be synonymous with “should/ought to”?

(By literal of course I don’t mean that inanimate objects have needs, literal would be that “need” is literally synonymous with “should/ought to”.)

Clarification: Nowadays some Spanish speakers in the USA use expressions literally translated from English saying that things have needs, but I deem that to be Spanglish.

Comment: "There is a necessity for someone to wash this floor."

Comment: What about it? I know that’s a possible equivalent.

Comment: I meant that an inanimate object doesn't literally have needs, as you say - the expression means that the necessity exists for something to happen.

Comment: @KateBunting Right, I understand that. My question was if it is taken to be literal or metaphorical. And by literal of course I don’t mean that inanimate objects have needs, literal would be that “need” is synonymous with “should/ought to”.

Comment: I agree with James that it isn't a metaphor either.

Comment: @KateBunting Why not? I’m not sure that he said that. He called it a figure of speech, which usually involve non-literal language

Comment: Read his last sentence!

Comment: @KateBunting I did. It says that he does not analyse it. Not that it is not a metaphor. Saying that it is not would require analysis. Why would you say that it is not?

Comment: In the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, if we say that somebody 'has needs' we often mean that they are disabled in some way, mentally or physically. My blind uncle has needs in the workplace, but I wouldn't say that a muddy floor 'has needs' that could be addressed using a mop and bucket.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, objects having needs is an Americanism I think. But we all have needs, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common figure of speech, so we don't think much about it at all.  If asked, I'd probably say that I understand "This floor needs to be washed" as being an alternative to "I need this floor washed" or "Someone needs..."
It is slightly stronger than "This floor should be washed", and more tactful than "Wash this floor!"

Which is to say, that I understand the figure of speech. I don't analyse it as literal or metaphorical.